# aws document db not working from node.js application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, aws-documentdb

express.js code

```js
    var mongoose = require("mongoose");
    const { db } = require("../../models/userModel");
    mongoose.connect("mongodb://cnoxbeta:abdf1234@cnox-beta-document-db.cluster-cvzxy5kwx8pn.us-west-2.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017/cnox?ssl=true&ssl_ca_certs=rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem&replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&retryWrites=false");
```

error:

```
    (node:1239) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line
        at Object.createSecureContext (_tls_common.js:149:17)
        at Object.connect (_tls_wrap.js:1580:48)
        at makeConnection (/home/ubuntu/cnox-webbackend/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connect.js:274:31)
        at connect (/home/ubuntu/cnox-webbackend/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connect.js:33:5)
        at checkServer (/home/ubuntu/cnox-webbackend/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/monitor.js:201:27)
        at /home/ubuntu/cnox-webbackend/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/monitor.js:231:9
        at executeAndReschedule (/home/ubuntu/cnox-webbackend/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:791:9)
        at makeInterruptibleAsyncInterval (/home/ubuntu/cnox-webbackend/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:798:9)
        at Monitor.connect (/home/ubuntu/cnox-webbackend/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/monitor.js:87:71)
        at Server.connect (/home/ubuntu/cnox-webbackend/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/server.js:100:28)
    (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

I am using aws document db to connect my node application .
I am able to access mongo db using shell so mongodb is fine and access ip whitelisting is fine. Something wrong in the connection .
Please take a look how can i fix this

Note: I am able to connect using shell

Answer (score 0):

Check the `Mongoose` version in the `package.json` file.

With version `v6+` you should not add `useNewUrlParser` and `useUnifiedTopology` options, so you should remove these options. Mongoose will set them to `true` by default.

Comment: (node:2959) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoParseError: option ssl_ca_certs is not supported

getting this error after remove

Comment: "mongodb://cnoxbeta:abcd1234@cnox-beta-document-db.cluster-cvzxy5kwx8pn.us-west-2.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017/cnox?ssl=true&ssl_ca_certs=rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem&replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&retryWrites=false"

Comment: My mongouri is like this

Comment: question updated  @NeNaD

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://<user>:<pass>@cnox-beta-document-db.cluster-cvzxy5kwx8pn.us-west-2.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017/cnox?replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&retryWrites=false', {
  ssl: true,
  sslValidate: true,
  sslCA: `path_to/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem`
});
```

[Reference](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/ssl.html#ssl-validation).

PS: You might want to remove the credentials from your initial question.